# C++ DLL project with C modules and error 2732

Tags: c, linker

I've added a C module to a mainly CPP DLL.  When I build the project using MSVC I get:

```
    error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'outputDebug'
```

There is another C module already in the project, I cannot see where the differences are and why the compiler isn't complaining about that module.

My header (debugHelper.h):

```
    #if defined(_DEBUG) && !defined(DEBUG_HELPER_H)
        #define DEBUG_HELPER_H

        #ifdef __cplusplus
        /*Prevents name mangling if including this file from C++ code */
            extern "C" {  
        #endif
        /*Function Prototypes*/
            void outputDebug(int intDelta
                            ,const char* cpszFile
                            ,unsigned uintLineNo
                            ,const char* cpszFormat, ...);
        #ifdef __cplusplus
            };
        #endif
    #endif
```

The source module (debugHelper.c):

```
    /**
     * File:    debugHelper.c
     * Notes:   Contains variables and functions to aid in generation 
     *          of debugging information
     *
     * History:
     *  2018/05/10  Written by Simon Platten
     */
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    /*Includes structures and external declarations */
    #include "debugHelper.h"
    /*Type definitions*/
    #ifndef ULONGLONG
        typedef unsigned long long ULONGLONG;
    #endif
    /**
     * Function:    outputDebug
     * Parameters:  intDelta        indent delta +1, -1 or 0
     *              cpszFile        Pointer to file name
     *              uintLineNo      Line number
     *              cpszFormat      Format string for parameters
     *              ...             Optional function parameters 
     * Adds a statement to the console
     * Usage:
     *  outputDebug(true | false, __FILE__, __LINE__, "Function Name(%d, %d)", 1, 2);
     */
    void outputDebug(int intDelta
                    ,const char* cpszFile
                    ,unsigned uintLineNo
                    ,const char* cpszFormat, ...) {
        static unsigned suintDbgIndents = 0, suintDbgSeqNo = 1;
        static const char scszPathPrefix[] = ".\\";
        static ULONGLONG sullngStartRef;
        static char sszIndents[80];

        unsigned uintIdx, uintIndent;
        char szPrefix[768], szOut[768];
        const char* cpszClipped;
        SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
        ULONGLONG ullngNow;
        FILETIME fileTime;
        float fltElapsed;
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, cpszFormat);
        GetLocalTime(&sysTime);

        if ( intDelta < 0 && suintDbgIndents != 0 ) {
        /*Decrement indents*/
            suintDbgIndents--;
        }
        /*Skip over leading '.\'*/
        if ( (cpszClipped = strstr(cpszFile, scszPathPrefix)) != NULL ) {
            cpszClipped += strlen(scszPathPrefix);
        }
        /*Calculate the elapsed time since application start-up*/
        SystemTimeToFileTime(&sysTime, &fileTime);
        ullngNow = (((ULONGLONG)fileTime.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + fileTime.dwLowDateTime;

        if ( sullngStartRef == 0 ) {
            sullngStartRef = ullngNow;
            fltElapsed = 0.0f;
        } else {
        /*FileTime is in 100 nanosecond intervals, convert to seconds with fraction ms*/
            fltElapsed = (float)(((double)ullngNow - (double)sullngStartRef) / 10000000.0);
        }
        /*Build the indents prefix*/        
        uintIdx = 0;
        sszIndents[uintIdx++] = ' ';
        for( uintIndent=0; uintIndent<suintDbgIndents; uintIndent++ ) {
            sszIndents[uintIdx++] = ' ';
            sszIndents[uintIdx++] = ' ';
        }
        sszIndents[uintIdx] = '\0';
        /*Build up formatted debug string including sequence number, line number
         *date and time stamp including milliseconds and message detail*/
        sprintf_s(szPrefix, sizeof(szPrefix)
                 ,"%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d DBG: E[%8.3f] S[%05u] L[%05u] F[%-24s]%s%s\n"           
                 ,sysTime.wYear, sysTime.wMonth, sysTime.wDay
                 ,sysTime.wHour, sysTime.wMinute, sysTime.wSecond
                 ,sysTime.wMilliseconds, fltElapsed, suintDbgSeqNo
                 ,uintLineNo, cpszClipped, sszIndents, cpszFormat);
        vsprintf_s(szOut, sizeof(szOut), szPrefix, ap); 
        va_end(ap);
        OutputDebugString(szOut);
        /*Increment sequence number*/
        if ( ++suintDbgSeqNo >= USHRT_MAX ) {
            suintDbgSeqNo = 1;
        }
        if ( intDelta > 0 ) {
        /*Increment indents*/
            suintDbgIndents++;
        }
    }
    #endif
```

On this file I have already ensured that "Not Using Precompiled Headers" is selected for "Create/Use Precompiled Header@ in the property pages for this C module.

Build output (this is a very old project and not originally written by myself):

```
    1>c:\projects\edwards scada\components\agents\lonworks\lon agent player\debugHelper.h(19) : error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'outputDebug'
    1>        c:\projects\edwards scada\components\agents\lonworks\lon agent player\debugHelper.h(16) : see declaration of 'outputDebug'
```

Does this help?

Comment: Please post the relevant build output. That one line is not sufficient to properly diagnose this problem. An [MCVE] would include whatever C++ code uses debugHelper.h, as that may actually be where the problem is.  Are you building the debug version of the code?

Comment: @jwdonahue, done, I've only posted the relevant bit.

Comment: And what was being compiled when that was spewed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somethere in your project there is already a declaration for outputDebug function, but with different linkage specifier. Look for all declarations of outputDebug and see they all have extern "C" specifier.

Acorrording to MSDN:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2732

> linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'function'
>
> The function is already declared with a different linkage specifier.
>
> This error can be caused by include files with different linkage specifiers.
>
> To fix this error, change the extern statements so that the linkages agree. In particular, do not wrap #include directives in extern "C" blocks.

Comment: Searched again and found the duplicate.